# How to show custom error message from API Gateway when getway timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

API gateway has a timeout upper limit of the 30s and it's getting triggered in our application use case. I want to pass on custom messages in place of request time out to end-user so that the end-user can take the next set of actions.

I have integration with the Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gateway responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-response-using-the-console.html).

There you will find `Integration Timeout` which you can edit and provide your own message, e.g.:

```
{"message": "my custom message"}
```

Don't forget to re-deploy your stage after changes.

Comment: Thanks. Missing part was the deployment of API in the stage. That solves this. Is it possible to have redirection to some other error page in the same use case?